# Parameterize script that serves as sub-tool of ModelBuilder of ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, modelbuilder, python-script-tool, parameters

The following script is used to place shapes inside a .mxd project:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import mapping

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\GIS\Test"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\GIS\Test\Mxd_to_shape.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

#Variables
shp_input = "hellow.shp"
layer_output = "test"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(shp_input,layer_output)
layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layer_output)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,layer,"AUTO_ARRANGE")

mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\GIS\Test\Mxd_a_shape2.mxd")
del mxd

arcpy.AddMessage("Ended process")
```

Later, I need to place said script as a sub-tool of a model builder, and also, that it be parameters all the variables so that the script works within the model. For example:

- arcpy.env.workspace
- shp_input
- layer_output
- mxd.saveACopy

To do the above, do I have to do some modification to the script or can it be done within the script properties in ArcCatalog, or both?

This is correct?:

[image]

Comment: [`arcpy.GetParameterAsText`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/getparameterastext.htm)